# Windows service unexpected termination logging

Tags: c#, windows, logging, windows-services, event-viewer

I want my Windows Service to log (log4net) error if the service terminates unexpectedly, i.e crashes due to any reason. I terminated the service from Windows Task Manager, checked Event Viewer i.e.

> Windows logs -> System

and found error was **7034**.

**Update:**

Here is what I tried, I used *EventLog* class for writing entry in Application log, which was successful. Although I want an entry to be written in case windows service crashes or terminates unexpectedly.

```
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do something here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists("ApplicationName"))
                EventLog.CreateEventSource("ApplicationName", "WindowsService");
            EventLog.WriteEntry("ApplicationName", ex.Message);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

But it didn't log anything upon crash, where should I write entry in *EventLog* so that it can log upon crash?

Comment: Please provide us with some idea of what your research has shown.  What did you find on this topic before you posted your question here?

Comment: I actually didn't find anything much helpful regarding this topic, which is why I posted a question here, if you have some topics related to it, sharing it will be a lot helpful.